# Why isn't this if statement working?

Tags: c, if-statement, fork, pid

I'm forking, and executing a certain block in the child process. My problem is that my child process never gets into the if statement. Why is this?

```
if((x = strcmp(subargs[next_redirect], ">")) == 0)
            {
                pid = fork();
                fprintf(stderr, "my PID is %i\n", pid);
                if(pid == 0)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "the name of our file is %s\n", subargs[i+1]);
                    fp = creat(subargs[i+1], S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR);
                    dup2(fp, STDOUT_FILENO);
                    close(fp);
                    //create sub-command
                    makesubcommand(subcommand, subargs, last_redirect + 1, i);
                    execvp(subcommand[0], subcommand);
                }
                last_redirect = i;
                next_redirect = getnextredirect(subargs, i+2, subargc);
            }
```

My output is

```
my PID is 11080
my PID is 0
```

When you fork, the child process receives a PID of 0, correct?

My problem is at `if(pid == 0){}`.  The code in that block never executes.

Comment: ur comparing string with charecter ....">" check once...

Comment: after forking you are waiting, why?

Comment: @vinod: I get to the fork just fine. my problem isnt the strcmp.

Comment: Your child mostly not coming out of `wait(0);`

Comment: The wait() system call suspends execution of the calling process until one of its children terminates. It will never get to the if(pid == 0) because it is waiting for the child process to terminate.

Comment: I moved wait(0); below the block and the problem is still persisting

Comment: You should exit after the `execvp()`, just in case `execvp()` returns, which means it has failed.  You might well print an error message too.  Have you included a print statement to check that you get to the `fork()`?  It is not immediately obvious why redirecting standard output causes you to fork, but that's your problem.

Comment: It is not a good idea to significantly modify your question in the middle of the answering process, as it could make certain answers ununderstandable.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: my code never gets to the execvp.. it doesn't even get into the if-statement, otherwise the first line of code in that block would print to stderr, and my problem wouldn't be a problem -.-

Comment: The advice about `exit()` after `execvp()` stands regardless of whether you're reaching the code.  Given that you have the `printf()` after the `fork()` and its output appears, but you don't see the other `printf()` output, your code is probably crashing in that `printf()`.  What is the value of `subargs[i+1]`?  Is it a null pointer?  Is it a wild pointer? _[…time passes…]_ This seems to be the correct diagnosis given the answer from the OP.

Comment: my problem was just that subargs needed to be malloc'd.
after that, everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies. It turns out that my problem was

```
fprintf(stderr, "the name of our file is %s\n", subargs[i+1]);
```

I was left thinking that the block was never executed because this wouldn't print anything.
it turns out that there is a problem with subargs.
I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your child process is not getting to `if` because of `wait()` system call.

The system call wait() blocks the calling process until one of its child processes exits or a signal is received.wait() takes the address of an integer variable and returns the process ID of the completed process. Some flags that indicate the completion status of the child process are passed back with the integer pointer. One of the main purposes of wait() is to wait for completion of child processes.

The execution of wait() could have two possible situations.

- If there are at least one child processes running when the call to wait() is made, the caller will be blocked until one of its child processes exits. At that moment, the caller resumes its execution.
- If there is no child process running when the call to wait() is made, then this wait() has no effect at all. That is, it is as if no wait() is there.

So remove the `wait()` system call. and your program will run ok.

Comment: `wait()` is after the `if`.

Comment: I removed wait(). I still cannot get into the if statement.

Comment: After forking can you try to print out pid and also try to use pid in this manner. See if it resolves.. 
<code>int child_id;
 printf ("Here I am in the program!\n");
 child_id = fork();
 if (child_id) {
         printf ("I'm the parent, about to die.  Bye now!\n");
 }
 else {
  printf ("I'm the child, about to die.  Bye now!\n");
  }</code>

Comment: I edited the code at the top, and added some debug lines like you suggested. The output is listed below the code, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Check the call of execvp in your code, which may have errors. You can check the return value of wait to get the child pid or -1.